# Wireless SSIDs restrictions for Windows Mac Ubuntu

Tags: wifi, network-security, endpoint, symantec-endpoint-protection, data-protector

I am an IT Admin and we are using Symanetc EndPoint protection, through this we have restricted external USB access.Now, I need to allow only office provided wireless access points to the office Endpoints (Desktops and Laptops), The endpoints should not be able to see and access any other wireless access points (can be employees personal wifi hotspots and neighbours wifi). The Symantec we are using (cloud SEPM 14.0) does not have the feature to configure this particular wireless restriction.

I have tried through Windows AD GPO also we are able to meet these restrictions but the personal hotspots and neighbors wireless will be accessible if they have the same wireless SSID name as whitelisted ones. and also this is only for Windows, we need this restrictions on Windows, Mac and Ubuntu endpoints

Is there any other Endpoints device control software we can use to meet my requirements ? please advise.

Thanks

Comment: This is a forum for products and solutions that you have. Requests for products and solutions are off topic.